# Loop through HTML table with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to loop over a HTML table and pick up values in a specific way with javascript.

My table looks like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="name">Henk</td>
        <td class="day">tuesday</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td></td>
        <td id="number_2">667</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="name">Jill</td>
        <td class="day">monday</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td id="number_5">77</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="name">Joe</td>
        <td class="day">wednesday</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td id="number_1">112</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="name">Henk</td>
        <td class="day">monday</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td id="number_3">345</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="name">Joe</td>
        <td class="day">friday</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td id="number_4">332</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

What I need to collect is:

```
 Henk,345,667,0,0,0
 Jill,77,0,0,0,0
 Joe,0,0,112,0,332
```

The names need to be collected one time only, and after that pick up the days that this person has a number listed in the number cell, will be sorted by weekdays (monday-friday). The days that there are no numbers can be filled with a '0'.

The table will be generated and can be of any length and in any specific order. So if I would refresh the page, the row-order can be changed (e.a. putting Jill,77 in the first row). The table and contents are generated with PHP, but the number-cell is filled by javascript. After that a button will be pressed to export the data with javascript. This will then be used as input for a csv file.
In the export, the 'text' values are ignored.

I can't seem to get the correct loop. How can I accomplish this with javascript?

Edit: I have no example code as everything I tried failed to deliver the right outcome.

Comment: Regardless, you should post the code you've tried as we might be able to work out what is wrong with it.

Comment: Will there only be a single <td> with a "number_x" id or multiple in a <tr> entry?  I am not clear on how the days work though, is there no correlation between the day of the week and the number?

Comment: Nest a loop: loop your table rows, loop the table cells and extract data. Full answer given if you provide your failing code.

Comment: I wrote too many different javascripts, but I never got close to the result, so after trying for days I'm just stuck and can't seem to 'get' it.

Comment: @BoudewijnCorbach please take a look at my answer you will find an explaned solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an id to your table, ex: tbl1 .
Then :

```
$(function(){
    $('#tbl1 tr').each(function() {
      $( this ).find('td').each(function() {
        console.log($(this).html());
      });
    });
});
```

Comment: There was a small error some brackets missing I updated the code

Comment: This is just a drop in the ocean from what the OP wants, this is far too different from the OP needs, it's just the first step and the id isn't necessary to get the table you can just use: `$('table')[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this,

```js
var data = {},
  res = '',
  days = ['monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday'];
$('table tr').each(function() {
  // iterate all tr using each()
  var $this = $(this),
    name = $this.find('td:first-child').text();
    // getting name from first column
  if (!data[name])
  // checking object added or not , if not then creating object with name and 0 valued array
    data[name] = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
  data[name][days.indexOf($this.find('td.day').text())] = $this.find('td[id^="number_"]').text();
   // finding number and inserting it based on day
});

$.each(data, function(i, v) {
// iterating object using $.each  
  res += i + ',' + v.join() + '\n';});
  // generating prefered string
alert(res);
console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="name">Henk</td>
    <td class="day">tuesday</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td></td>
    <td id="number_2">667</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="name">Jill</td>
    <td class="day">monday</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td id="number_5">77</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="name">Joe</td>
    <td class="day">wednesday</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td id="number_1">112</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="name">Henk</td>
    <td class="day">monday</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td id="number_3">345</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="name">Joe</td>
    <td class="day">friday</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td id="number_4">332</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I like this solution! I used it in the final script... Thanks

Comment: @BoudewijnCorbach : glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple method using Jquery "each" and formatting your data in json.

```js
/* json formatted data */
var data = [
  {"id":"1","name":"Henk","day":"Friday"},
  {"id":"2","name":"Jill","day":"Monday"},
  {"id":"3","name":"Joe","day":"Saturday"}
];


$(document).ready(function(){
 var html='';
 if(data != null){
  $.each(data,function(i,val){
   var id = val.id,
    name = val.name,
    day = val.day;
    
    html+='<tr> \
     <th scope="row" id="number_'+id+'">'+id+'</th> \
     <td>'+name+'</td> \
     <td>'+day+'</td> \
     <td>text</td> \
     </tr>';
  });
  
  $(html).appendTo('.results');
  
  }else{
  
   html='';
   alert('No data available');
    
  $('.results').empty();
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>#ID</th>
   <th>Name</th>
   <th>Day</th>
   <th> - - - </th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody class="results">
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some js (with jquery) that spits out desired output:

```
Henk: 345, 667, 0, 0, 0
Jill: 77, 0, 0, 0, 0
Joe: 112, 332, 0, 0, 0
```

for the html structure provided.

```
var people = {};
$.each($('table').children().children(), function(index, value) {
    var thisElement = $(value).children();
    var thisName = $(thisElement[0]).text()
    ,   thisValue = parseInt($(thisElement[7]).text());
    if(typeof people[thisName] === "undefined") {
        people[thisName] = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
        people[thisName][0] = thisValue;
    } else {
        for(index = 0; index < 5; index ++) {
            var curValue = people[thisName][index];
            if(curValue == 0 || curValue > thisValue) {
                people[thisName][index] = thisValue;
                thisValue = curValue;
            }
        }
    }
});
for(index in people) {
    console.log(index + ',' + people[index]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I gaved the table an id of "table" and then I did this:

```
var tbody = document.getElementById("table").children;
var array = new Array();
var aux_name, aux_number;
for( var i = 0; i < tbody.item(0).children.length ; i++){
    if(tbody.item(0).children[i] != undefined){
        aux_name = tbody.item(0).children[i].children[0].innerText;
        array[aux_name] = "";
    }
}

for( var i = 0; i < tbody.item(0).children.length ; i++){ // tr
        if(tbody.item(0).children[i] != undefined)
        {
            aux_name = tbody.item(0).children[i].children[0].innerText;
            aux_number = tbody.item(0).children[i].children[7].innerText;
            if(array[aux_name] != 0){
                var aux_new_value = array[aux_name].concat(", " + aux_number);
                array[aux_name] = aux_new_value;

            } else {
                array[aux_name] = aux_number;
            }
            fillArray(array, aux_name);
        }    
}

function fillArray(array, except){
    for( var i = 0 ; i < Object.keys(array).length ; i++){
        if(Object.keys(array)[i] != except){
            array[Object.keys(array)[i]] = array[Object.keys(array)[i]] == "" ? array[Object.keys(array)[i]].concat("0") : array[Object.keys(array)[i]].concat(", 0");    
        }            
    }
}
console.log(array);
```

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is quite simple, all you have to do is to:

- Change your HTML code a little bit by replacing the `id` in your numbers `td` with a common `class` so the parsing will be much simplier.
- Loop over the table rows and store unique names in an array.
- Create an empty `persons` array that will hold all the persons.
- Loop over the `names` array, then for each `name` :

  1. Create a person object that will holds its details (`name, points`).
  2. Assign the `name` property to this `person` object.
  3. Create a points array initialized with zeros to hold the numbers/points of each day.
  4. Loop again over the table rows and whenever you find this `name` get the found days and update the points array with relevant numbers.
  5. And finally assign the points array to your person object.

And finally just Print the wanted output as shown in the following DEMO.

```js
var table = $('table')[0];
console.log(table.rows);

var persons = [];
var names = [];
var days = ['monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday'];

$('table#myTable tr').each(function() {
  var row = $(this);
  var name = row.find('td.name').html();
  if ($.inArray(name, names) === -1) {
    names.push(name);
  }
});

for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
  var name = names[i];
  var person = {};
  person.name = name;
  var points = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
  $('table#myTable tr').each(function() {
    var row = $(this);
    var nameInTd = row.find('td.name').html();
    var dayInTd = row.find('td.day').html();
    if (name === nameInTd) {
      for (day in days) {
        if (days[day] === dayInTd) {
          points[day] = row.find('td.number').html();
        }
      }
    }
  });
  person.points = points;
  $("#output").html($("#output").html() + person.name + ", " + person.points.join(", ") + "<br>");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td class="name">Henk</td>
    <td class="day">tuesday</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="number">667</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="name">Jill</td>
    <td class="day">monday</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td class="number">77</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="name">Joe</td>
    <td class="day">wednesday</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="number">112</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="name">Henk</td>
    <td class="day">monday</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td class="number">345</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="name">Joe</td>
    <td class="day">friday</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="number">332</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<h4>This is the result</h4>
<p id="output">

</p>
```

**This is the JavaScript code:**

```
var table = $('table')[0];
console.log(table.rows);

var persons = [];
var names = [];
var days = ['monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday'];

$('table#myTable tr').each(function() {
  var row = $(this);
  var name = row.find('td.name').html();
  if ($.inArray(name, names) === -1) {
    names.push(name);
  }
});

for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
  var name = names[i];
  var person = {};
  person.name = name;
  var points = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
  $('table#myTable tr').each(function() {
    var row = $(this);
    var nameInTd = row.find('td.name').html();
    var dayInTd = row.find('td.day').html();
    if (name === nameInTd) {
      for (day in days) {
        if (days[day] === dayInTd) {
          points[day] = row.find('td.number').html();
        }
      }
    }
  });
  person.points = points;
  $("#output").html($("#output").html() + person.name + ", " + person.points.join(", ") + "<br>");
}
```